# How to add external CSS while converting HTML to PDF in PHP

Tags: dompdf

I am trying to generate PDF from HTML template with external css file but I am getting is empty pdf with the below code. I need both css & HTML. I tried all the possible ways but not sure what I am missing to get the pdf generated.

```
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
       $dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'Courier');
       $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);

       $html = '*<section id="main-container" class="main-container">Some title here</section>*'; // html ends. here
       $html .= '**<link type="text/css" href="http://servicequeststaffing.com/application/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />**'; // external css included, I have tried to give it's relative path here but still did not work
       $dompdf->loadHtml($html); // loading html
```